# UserName when using ADFS

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, adfs

Hi I am changing my MVC 5 Application to do Authentication via ADFS.

Withing my global.asax.cs file in SessionStart I have the following method:

```
DoUserLogIn(Request.LogonUserIdentity, Session);
```

Simplified method implementation is below

```
private void DoUserLogIn(WindowsIdentity user, HttpSessionState session)
{
  session["UserDisplayName"] = user.Name;
}
```

This was working before ADFS and the userName displayed.  However now with ADFS the UserName that is getting displayed is the Service Account User that the Application is running under in IIS.  What should I be using to get the Actual User Name of the User accessing the Application with SSO with ADFS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have setup in the most common fashion you should be able to access the current user's name by accessing the ClaimsPrincipal class:

Use Thread.CurrentPrincipal and make sure it is an ClaimsPrincipal before using it.

i.e. (Thread.CurrentPrincipal as System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal).Identity

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.claims.claimsidentity(v=vs.110).aspx

The name property on the ClaimsIdentity class should give you what you want